In the Haskell conduit library, why is the .| operator infixr?
In the conduit library, the .| operator used to connect two conduits is infixr (right associative). This means that the last component in the pipeline is always nested within all the other components in the pipeline.
Also, the .| operator is always strict in its right argument. This means that when running a pipeline, the code would have to recurse starting from the first component, all the way down to the last component and then unwind all the way back when the last component yields input or a result. This applies even if the last component is something like return (), which returns immediately without demanding input from other components.
If .| were left associative, then the conduit would be able to exit immediately without recursing, if the last component is immediately short circuiting.
And so why is .| right associative? From a performance standpoint, it seems almost always disadvantageous to me for .| to be right associative, since it results in needless recursion. Is there some advantage that I am unaware of?
Here is an example. Suppose I have the pipeline:
yieldMany [0..10] .| mapC (*2) .| mapC (+4) .| return ()

Because the .| operator is right associative, this code desugars to:
yieldMany [0..10] .| (mapC (*2) .| (mapC (+4) .| return ()))

When evaluating a pipeline, the .| operator is immediately strict in its right argument. This means that to evaluate the code above, the caller evaluates the leftmost .| because it is at the top of the expression tree. It then evaluates the middle .|, which then evaluates the rightmost .| before reaching the return () statement. The code then determines that it does not need to evaluate any other components, and goes all the way back up before exiting.
If the .| operator was left associative, then the expression would desugar to the following instead:
((yieldMany [0..10] .| mapC (*2)) .| mapC (+4)) .| return ()

Now, the topmost .| in the expression tree and the first to be evaluated is the rightmost .|. The rightmost .| evaluates the return () expression, sees it does not need to evaluate anymore components, and immediately exits. No recursion necessary.

The final component is deeper in the parse tree, but its the first thing that gets evaluated, because the upstream part of the conduit only gets evaluated to the extend needed to produce a value for the conduit as a hole.

I understand, but that was not my question. I believe my description was poor, and so I just edited the question and added an example to make it easier to understand. Thank you though. Because the .| operator is right associative, the final component becomes the deepest component in the parse tree. To evaluate the final component, the code has to recurse all the way down the parse tree, get the result, then go back up. But if the .| operator is left associative, the final component becomes the topmost component in the parse tree. Now the code does not have to recurse to access it.

The parse tree isn't traversed at runtime; it's used to generate code that starts with the final component.

I don't believe that is true. Yes, the pipeline does not demand additional input if the final component does not request it, and in that sense you could say the "result" "starts" with the final component. But due to GHC's evaluation model / operational semantics and how the source code of conduit works, the actual evaluation that computes that result starts at whatever is at the top of the parse/expression tree and works its way down to the bottom.

I recommend reading these articles for anyone who is unfamiliar with how Haskell evaluates expressions: https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/lazy-eval.html

A big problem with your question is that -- let's be honest -- no one cares how quickly conduit processes a pipeline that ends in return ().  I would suggest replacing return () with sumC and bumping it up to yieldMany [0.1000000].  Run some Criterion benchmarks on left and right associative versions, and add the results to your question.  That's going to get people interested.

I thought it was worth filing an issue on this.  The developers might have a quick answer.

Thank you for filing an issue. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar yet with how to benchmark code, and so I neglected to include benchmarks. I should probably learn more about that.
